# Can I branch on argument type to parameter pack in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, parameter-pack

Current (old) function call signature:

```
        long vmcall(const std::string& function_name,
                    std::vector<address_t> args);
```

Now since I can only call into the guest using (address-sized) integers, this is quite a limited interface, and I want to expand it to at least also handle floating point values, and possibly others, like so:

```
        template <typename... Args>
        long vmcall(const std::string& function_name,
                    Args&&... args);
```

That will be the new function signature, replacing the old one.

To show how the args vector is currently used:

```
template <int W>
inline void Machine<W>::setup_call(
        address_t call_addr, address_t retn_addr,
        std::vector<address_t> args)
{
    assert(args.size() <= 8);
    cpu.reg(RISCV::REG_RA) = retn_addr;
    for (size_t arg = 0; arg < args.size(); arg++) {
        cpu.reg(RISCV::REG_ARG0 + arg) = args[arg];
    }
    cpu.jump(call_addr);
}
```

This function is called from vmcall with std::move(args), and all it does is copy the integer arguments in the args vector into the integral CPU registers, incrementally. This works fine when I want to call a function that only takes integral arguments. So, if I wanted to call a function that, say, takes one floating-point argument, then there is no way to do that. This is because FP registers are completely separate, and need to be handled differently.

Also, 32-bit and 64-bit floats are handled differently through NaN-boxing. So, it would be nice if it was possible to differentiate between float and double as well.

I'm not so strong on template magic to begin with. How do I branch on the type of each element in the parameter pack?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. In your example you don't call `vmcall`. And I don't get how you use fp registers. I also don't know what fp registers are (as data types in your program). You need to provide more context and explication. A [MRE] would be ideal

Comment: I updated my question a bit now, hopefully it explains my problem better. But the gist of it is that I want to go from calling using a std::vector<integer> to a parameter pack so that I can support both integers and floating-point values as arguments to vmcall. The new API replaces the old one.

Then, inside the function I need to be able to (for each parameter) be able to branch on the type of each argument, so that I can put all integers in one place and all floating-points in another place.

Comment: I believe this calls for `enable_if`, tag dispatching, or explicit template specialization...there are a number of approaches, depending on your use case.

Comment: Also, you can't convert a vector of integers into parameter packs. Parameter packs are generated at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: I am not converting the vector to a parameter pack, this will just replace the old API with the new call signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17, the way to iterate over a parameter pack is to use a comma [fold](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
(<expr>, ...); // expr contains Args and/or args
```

If a single expression is insufficient, you can use an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
([&] {
    <statements> // statements contains Args and/or args
 }(), ...);
```

Combine this with `if constexpr` on the types of your arguments:

```
std::vector<address_t> addr_args;
std::vector<fp_t> fp_args;
([&] {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<Args>)
        addr_args.push_back(args);
    else
        fp_args.push_back(args);
 }(), ...);
```